# In R can I set dygraph to resize to window size?

Tags: r, dygraphs

In R can I set dygraph to resize to browser window size?
(for example as percentage of browser view?)

I can see in link below that dygraph can do it but from R I only seem to be able to set a fixed width in pixels. 
http://dygraphs.com/tests/resize.html

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set the `width` parameter to `auto`:

```
dygraphs::dygraph(data = ..., width = 'auto')
```

I had a similar issue using using `dygraph` through `renderUI` in the body of a `shiny` app.
`auto` allowed to use full body width.